# cache repository's result or maybe sql server does it for me

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, caching, repository

I have repositories like this in my application

```
public class FooRepo
{
    public Foo Get(int id)
    {
       return Foo from Db;
    }
}
```

I'm just wondering if there is possible to do some caching for the methods inside the repository, or probably there is no need because sql-server does it for me, but if needed could someone point/show me some solutions

thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends.  Caching  IN The repository is a LOT faster than asking the database. For many data items it makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

[LINQ queries can be cached using SqlDependency active caching](http://code.google.com/p/linqtocache/). SqlDependency relies on [Query Notifications](http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/) to get invalidation notifications from the server when the data has changed.